# Convert multiples row into one rows based on master key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following records on my table. I want to convert these records into one single row based on master key.

```
records:-
id     date        userkey workinghours  masterkey
1941   2016-06-01    1         6           NULL
1946   2016-06-08    1         1           NULL
1947   2016-06-09    1         6           1946
1948   2016-06-10    1         3           1946
```

I want output like this.

```
id     startdate   endate     userkey workinghours  masterkey
1941   2016-06-01  2016-06-01    1      6            NULL
1946   2016-06-08  2016-06-10    1      10           1946
```

How can i do this ? As a newbie I need your help to write this query.

Comment: On what basis does the `workinghours` get values 6, 10 in the output

Comment: and how does the 1946 id gets masterkey 1946 in the output, while in the sample data it's masterkey is null?

Comment: when record has group key i want to sum the workinghours @jonju

Comment: How is the pair of startdate and endate defined?

Comment: because 1946 is master record @ZoharPeled

Comment: The closest solution for you would be to use GROUP BY masterkey, but as @jonju pointed out, you need to tell SQL Server which rows should be chosen. You can either use a where clause or aggregate functions like MIN(), MAX(), SUM(), etc. In your example the duplicates are deleted but you did not provide the key on which the duplicates should be eliminated.

Comment: then isn't it suppose to be 7, 9 ?

Comment: u can min( ),max( )do group by  masterkey but this will not work in case of null value in masterkey  ....

Comment: you need to use group by. take a look at that. by the way, either your sample input or output is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it, using `ISNULL` and `GROUP BY`:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE
(
    id int,
    [date] date,
    userkey int,
    workinghours int, 
    masterkey int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1941, '2016-06-01', 1, 6, NULL),
(1946, '2016-06-08', 1, 1, NULL),
(1947, '2016-06-09', 1, 6, 1946),
(1948, '2016-06-10', 1, 3, 1946)
```

The query:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(MasterKey, id) as id,
        MIN([date]) as startdate,
        MAX([date]) as enddate,
        userkey,
        SUM(workinghours) as workinghours,
        MIN(masterKey) as masterKey
FROM @T  
GROUP BY ISNULL(MasterKey, id), userkey
```

Result:

```
id          startdate  enddate    userkey     workinghours masterKey
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ------------ -----------
1941        2016-06-01 2016-06-01 1           6            NULL
1946        2016-06-08 2016-06-10 1           10           1946
```

Comment: Nicer and more elegant way both with the `ISNULL` and both already doing it in a single select

Comment: This is incorrect because the end date of first record should be '2016-06-01'

Comment: @Ket Good catch! However, the reason is that I've edited my answer but forgot to update the results paragraph. Now it's updated with the actual results and as you can see, it matches the desired results stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE
(
    id int,
    [date] date,
    userkey int,
    workinghours int, 
    masterkey int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1941, '2016-06-01', 1, 6, NULL),
(1946, '2016-06-08', 1, 1, NULL),
(1947, '2016-06-09', 1, 6, 1946),
(1948, '2016-06-10', 1, 3, 1946)


SELECT
    MIN(ISNULL(masterkey,id)) as Id, 
    MIN([date]) as StartDate, 
    MAX([date]) as EndDate, 
    min(userkey) As Userkey, 
    sum(workinghours) As WorkingHours, 
    MIN(MasterKey) AS MasterKey
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        id ,
        date ,
        userkey ,
        workinghours ,
        masterkey,
        ISNULL(masterkey, id) TmpMasterkey
    FROM @T     
) A
GROUP BY TmpMasterkey
```

OUTPUT

```
Id      StartDate   EndDate     Userkey WorkingHours    MasterKey
1941    2016-06-01  2016-06-01  1       6               NULL
1946    2016-06-08  2016-06-10  1       10              1946
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
create table #tbl
(id     INT
, dt date        
, userkey INT
, workinghours  INT 
, masterkey INT
)

INSERT INTO #tbl VALUES
(1941   ,'2016-06-01'  ,  1         ,6           ,NULL)
,(1946   ,'2016-06-08'    ,1         ,1           ,NULL)
,(1947   ,'2016-06-09'    ,1         ,6           ,1946)
,(1948   ,'2016-06-10'    ,1         ,3           ,1946)

WITH WORKHOURS_CTE (
    ID
    ,origdate
    ,userkey
    ,workinghours
    ,masterkey
    )
AS
    -- Define the CTE query.  
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN masterkey IS NULL THEN id ELSE masterkey END AS ID
        ,dt
        ,userkey
        ,workinghours
        ,masterkey
    FROM #tbl
    )
-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.  
SELECT ID
    ,MIN(origdate) AS STARTDATE
    ,MAX(origdate) AS ENDDATE
    ,SUM(workinghours) AS workinghours
    ,userkey
    ,MAX(masterkey) AS masterkey
FROM WORKHOURS_CTE
GROUP BY ID
    ,userkey;
```